# How to round off decimal number to 2 places in Velocity template engine?

Tags: velocity

How can i round off decimal number to 2 places in Velocity Template Engine?

```
#set ($Percentage = $Marks*100/$Total)
```

I want to round off Percentage to 2 decimal places. How can i do that?

will `Double roundTo(Object decimals, Object num)` this work? i.e.

will `#set ($Percentage = roundTo(2, $Marks*100/$Total))` work? will I have to include anything in .vm file to make this work?

Answer (score 14):

Use the `MathTool` from the `VelocityTools` project.

```
$math.roundTo(2, $value)
```

Remember to put the `MathTool` in your context: `context.put("math", new MathTool())`  or use `VelocityTools` context support to automatically provide tools when you use them.

### P.S.

Don't forget adding maven dependency for velocity `math` tool:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please answer my question in more detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if `$value=12` it return `12.0`, how do I make it return `12.00` instead ?

Comment: That's not rounding, that's formatting.  Look at the NumberTool for that.

Comment: Also remember to *use the arguments in the proper order*. I couldn't for the life of me figure out why my number e.g. `123.456` was being "rounded" to `2.0`. :)