# Mulitiplication operation not working in velocity template

Tags: java, spring, email, velocity, sap-commerce-cloud

My velocity version is 1.7 The multiplication of variable not working in my vm file

```
foreach( $entry in ${ctx.order.entries} )

#if(${entry.quantity})
    #set ($pQty = ${entry.quantity})
#end
#if(${entry.product.weight})
    #set ($prodWeight = ${entry.product.weight})
#end
#if(${pQty} && ${prodWeight})
    #set ($totalWeight = $pQty * $prodWeight)       
#else
    #set ($totalWeight = 0)     
#end
  <tr class="border_bottom table_data">
  <td>${pQty }</td>
  <td>${prodWeight}</td>
  <td>${totalWeight}</td>
```

Output is 11     1.0             ${totalWeight}

totalWeight value is not getting displayed.

if I put hardcode value like 11*1.0 then its calculate correctly but not able to  calculate when i use $totalWeight = $pQty * $prodWeight

It would be appreciable if you will help me on this.

Thanks,

Comment: User (mathTool)[https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.3/generic/MathTool.html]

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7421367/808891

Answer (score 2):

One or both of your references must be strings instead of numbers. You can check it by displaying `$pQty.class.name` and `$prodWeight.class.name`.

Velocity 1.7 doesn't do any implicit conversion from strings to numbers.

To get it right, you can either:

- upgrade to Velocity 2.0, which handles such implicit conversions
- make sure that $pQty and $prodWeight are numbers in the calling code
- add the [MathTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/tools-summary.html#MathTool) (or any plain Java object of your own doing the same thing) to the Velocity context:

  ```
  #set($pQty = $math.toNumber($pQty))
  #set($prodWeight = $math.toNumber($prodWeight))
  ```

Comment: my $pQty.class.name is java.lang.Long  and $prodWeight.class.name. is java.lang.String ..

Comment: yes...... resolved  by using   this `#if(${entry.product.weight})
  #set($Double = 0.0)
  #set($prodWeight=$Double.parseDouble(${entry.product.weight}))
 #end

 #set ($totalWeight = ${entry.quantity} * $prodWeight) 
`