# Velocity showing dollar sign after changing from struts 1.3 to struts 2.5

Tags: java, struts2, velocity

Im stuck in velocity file, migrating from struts 1.3 to struts 2.5, after migrate to struts 2.5, I unable to see record from App layer. It's showing dollar sign(you can refer to image. I will post my velocity code and sturts 2.5 file as well. I need favor.

*Velocity file:*

```
<tr>
        <td class="distable" colspan="3">
            <table border='0' width=100% align=center cellspacing="1" cellpading="1" class="thetable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="distitle" width=30%>User Name</td>
                    <td class="distitle" width=15%><=2</td>
                    <td class="distitle" width=15%>>2</td>
                    <td class="distitle" width=15%>Total</td>
                    <td class="distitle" width=10%>TAT(%)</td>
                </tr>
                       #set($totalEarly = 0)
                       #set($totalLate = 0)
                       #if(!$list.isEmpty($request.getAttribute('finalRes')))
                            #foreach( $res in $request.getAttribute('finalRes') )
                                #set($totalEarly = $totalEarly+$res.EARLY)
                                #set($totalLate = $totalLate+$res.LATE)
                            #end
                       #foreach( $res in $request.getAttribute('finalRes') )
                                                    #set ($index = $loopIndex + 1)
            #set ($color = "tbltxt1" )
            #if (($index % 2) > 0 )
            #set ($color = "tbltxt2")   
            #end    
                      <tr>
                        <td class='$color'><div style="padding-left:10px">$!{res.SNAME}</div></td>
                        <td class='$color'>$!{res.EARLY}</td>
                ##      <td class='$color'><a id="lnkDataEntryReportDetails"  onClick="window.open('$request.contextPath/detail.do?q=det&type=de&month=$params.month&year=$params.year&brchCode=$params.brchCode&uid=$res.USERID')">$!{res.LATE}</a></td>
                         <td class='$color'><a href="#"  onClick="window.open('$request.contextPath/detail.do?q=det&type=de&month=$params.month&year=$params.year&brchCode=$params.brchCode&uid=$res.USERID'); return false">$!{res.LATE}</a></td>
                        <td class='$color'>$math.add($res.EARLY,$res.LATE)</td>
                        <td class='$color'>$math.roundTo(2,$math.mul($math.div($res.EARLY,$math.add($res.EARLY,$res.LATE)),100)) </td>
                      </tr>
                       #end
                        <tr>
                        <td class="tbltxt2 total"><div style="padding-left:10px">Grand Total</div></td>
                        <td class="tbltxt2 total">$!{totalEarly}</td>
                        <td class="tbltxt2 total">$!{totalLate}</td>
                        <td class="tbltxt2 total">$math.add($totalEarly,$totalLate)</td>
                        <td class="tbltxt2 total">$math.roundTo(2,$math.mul($math.div($totalEarly,$math.add($totalEarly,$totalLate)),100)) </td>
                      </tr>
                      #else
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="13" class="tbltxt2">No Results Returned</td>
                        </tr>
                      #end
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Struts 2.5.xml file:

```
<action name="dePerfReport" class="com.ifc.am.web.workflow.ReportAction"
        method="dePerf">
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
        <result name="success" type="velocity">/views/uw/uw.rep.dePerf.vm</result>
    </action>
```

Java method:

```
public String ReportExample() throws Exception{

    Muser user =    (Muser) getServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("muser");
    long userid = 0;
    if(user!=null){
         userid = user.getLseqid(); 
    }


    String month = request.getParameter("year") == null ?  "" : request.getParameter("month").trim() ;
    String year = request.getParameter("month") == null ?  "" : request.getParameter("year").trim() ;
    String brchCode = request.getParameter("brchCode") == null ?  "" : request.getParameter("brchCode").trim() ;
    List brch = new DaoUtil().getBrch();

    //log.debug(month+"-->"+year+"brchCode:"+brchCode);

    List result = new ArrayList(); 
    if(month.length() > 0 && year.length() > 0 && brchCode.length() > 0)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionInstance();               
        try {
            result = session.createSQLQuery(SQL.RPT_DE_PERFORMANCE)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
            .setParameter("MONTH", month)
            .setParameter("YEAR", year)
            .setParameter("BRANCH", brchCode)
            //.setParameter("USERID", userid)
            .list();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            log.fatal(e.getClass()+"[ "+e.getMessage()+" ]");
            HibernateUtil.closeSessionInstanceWithOutFlush(session);
        }catch (Exception e1) {
            log.fatal(e1.getClass()+"[ "+e1.getMessage()+" ]");
            HibernateUtil.closeSessionInstanceWithOutFlush(session);
        }
        finally {
            HibernateUtil.closeSessionInstance(session);
        }
    }

    request.setAttribute("year", year);
    request.setAttribute("month", month);
    request.setAttribute("brchCode", brchCode);
    request.setAttribute("finalRes", result);
    request.setAttribute("brch", new DaoUtil().getBrch());

    return SUCCESS;     

}
```

[This image is output from velocity file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYmqg.png)

Comment: how do you build your project ? maven? did you include MathTool ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415805/how-to-round-off-decimal-number-to-2-places-in-velocity-template-engine

Comment: yes, i build my project using maven. I did include MathTool in Toolbox.xml

Comment: <tool>
  <key>math</key>
  <scope>application</scope>
  <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.MathTool</class>
 </tool>

Comment: also "put the MathTool in your context: context.put("math", new MathTool()) or use VelocityTools context support to automatically provide tools when you use them."

Comment: you mean context.xml file?
by the way, i already add dependency in pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issues, please use velocity 1.7 and velocity-tools 1.4. Struts 2.5 didn't support higher version of velocity. please check your jar file in your eclipse as well. Some cases, same jar will be duplicate in your project.

Comment: actually, jar file have issue with struts 2.5. I recommend to use spring framework